# Function called twice in simple web server using Iron

Tags: rust, iron

I have a super simple web server, and for some reason the `println!` statement is printed out twice. Why could this be?

```
extern crate iron;

use iron::prelude::*;
use iron::status;

fn hello_world(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    println!("Said Hello World");
    Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, "Hello World\n")))
}

fn main() {
    Iron::new(hello_world).http("localhost:8000").unwrap();
}
```

Every time I refresh my browser the output in the shell is:

```
Said Hello World
Said Hello World
```

I would only expect the line to be printed out once.It seems that my `hello_world` functions is being called twice. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser might be automatically trying to fetch `favicon.ico`. Check the contents of the `Request` to know for sure! :) Your browser may also have a network monitor as part of its developer tools; this should show you the request for `favicon.ico` (I know it does in Firefox, don't know about other browsers).

Comment: Thank you. In my case it was google chrome that lead to two log lines, firefox to one log line. So the issue seems to be with the browser.